# Reactjs - How to pass values from child component to grand-parent component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

Below is correct example for passing the values from child component to parent component in reactjs.

**App.jsx**

```
import React from 'react';

class App extends React.Component {

   constructor(props) {
      super(props);
        
      this.state = {
         data: 'Initial data...'
      }

      this.updateState = this.updateState.bind(this);
   };

   updateState() {
      this.setState({data: 'Data updated from the child component...'})
   }

   render() {
      return (
         <div>
            <Content myDataProp = {this.state.data} 
               updateStateProp = {this.updateState}></Content>
         </div>
      );
   }
}

class Content extends React.Component {

   render() {
      return (
         <div>
            <button onClick = {this.props.updateStateProp}>CLICK</button>
            <h3>{this.props.myDataProp}</h3>
         </div>
      );
   }
}

export default App;
```

**main.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import App from './App.jsx';

ReactDOM.render(<App/>, document.getElementById('app'));
```

I need clear my concept about passing the values from child component to grand-parent component. Please, help me for this!!.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can pass the update function to the grand child by `props`, just pass it again from the child component.

```js
class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      data: 'Initial data...'
    }
    this.updateState = this.updateState.bind(this);
  }

  updateState(who) {
    this.setState({data: `Data updated from ${who}`})
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        Parent: {this.state.data}
        <Child update={this.updateState}/>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

class Child extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        Child component
        <button onClick={() => this.props.update('child')}>
          CLICK
        </button>
        <GrandChild update={this.props.update}/>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

class GrandChild extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        Grand child component
        <button onClick={() => this.props.update('grand child')}>
          CLICK
        </button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: this approach of passing value to parent reference hierarchy really helped me, specially the `onClick={() => this.props.update('child-value')}`

Answer (score 9):

The most straightforward way is to pass updateState functions as far down the tree as they need to go. Ideally, your grandchild component is thought of as completely separate from the grandparent component... though that quickly becomes tedious.

That's what [React Redux](https://github.com/reactjs/react-redux) is for. It creates a global state object with a publish/subscribe model. (The publish/subscribe model is somewhat abstracted away through a "connect" wrapper.) You can dispatch actions from anywhere, to anywhere. Actions trigger "reducers", which transform the global state, and React reacts to the modified state by re-rendering components (in a surprisingly efficient way).

For small programs, Redux can be overkill. If you really do just have the grandparent/parent/grandchild in your model, just pass the updateState functions. As your program grows, try replacing them with Redux. It can be hard to learn (especially since IMHO the standard tutorials are simply awful), but it's the intended solution to the general problem you're describing.