# How to pass callback function from child to parent to grandparent?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, parent-child

Most of the answers are for child to parent callback. But I want to go a step further. How do I send the callback from parent to grandparent? Is that even possible? I'm a starter, so please consider if I sound a noob. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Use the same aproach as from child to parent it shouldn't be hard

Comment: Agree. https://medium.com/@ruthmpardee/passing-data-between-react-components-103ad82ebd17

Comment: something like a http://callbackhell.com/  ?

Comment: Same approach as child to parent. Add another layer where parent calls its own parent passing data received from child component.

Comment: @JonathanHamel yes, I am also thinking in that way. but in child to parent callback there is button in child so data passes from child to parent but now I don't know how to pass this parent data to grand parent. I mean how can I call a function in parent that can directly send data to grandparent.

Comment: Pass it along using props, from component to grand child. I think you can just follow this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41121667/reactjs-how-to-pass-values-from-child-component-to-grand-parent-component

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to pass down the callback function from the grandfather component to the father component as props and have the father component pass down that callback function (from the grandfather component) to the child as props.

If you are passing around callback functions across a couple of generations of components (your case, three generations, is simple enough), you might want to look into something like Redux to help simplify your application.